# Is it possible to create an unlinked file on a selected filesystem?

Tags: c, linux, inode

Basically, the same result as creating a temporary file in the desired file system, opening it, and then unlinking it.

Even better, though unlikely, if this could be done without creating an inode that is visible to other processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to do so is OS-specific, since the relevant POSIX function calls all result in a link being generated. Linux in particular has allowed, since version 3.11, the use of `O_TMPFILE` in the `flags` argument of [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) in order to create an anonymous file in a given directory.

Comment: It looks like `O_TMPFILE` is actually used under-the-hood, when available, for better implementing `tmpfile(3)` (mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are several POSIX APIs at your disposal:

- [`mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) - generates a unique temporary filename from
     template, creates and opens the file, and returns an open file
     descriptor for the file.
- [`tmpfile`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) - opens a unique temporary file in binary
     read/write (w+b) mode.  The file will be automatically deleted when
     it is closed or the program terminates.

Both of these functions *do* create files on the filesystem. Creating an inode is unavoidable, if you want to use a real file.

The first provides you a *file descriptor* for making low-level system calls, like `read` and `write`. The second gives you a `FILE*` for all of the `<stdio.h>` APIs.

If you don't need/desire an *actual* file on disk, you should consider the [*memory stream* APIs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) provided by POSIX.1-2008.

- `open_memstream()` - opens a stream for writing to a buffer.
     The buffer is dynamically allocated (as with `malloc(3)`), and
     automatically grows as required.

Answer (score 1):

[libtmpfilefd : create a temporary unnamed file](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libtmpfilefd)  seem to fullfill your requirements

Looking at the [source file](http://sme.swerts-knudsen.dk/downloads/SpamFilter/Image_Spam/netpbm-10.26.32/lib/libpm.c) this function create a temporary file with `mkstemp` then unlink the file right after

Comment: `"This library function is part of Netpbm(1)."` ...which I've never even heard of. It seems like a pretty *heavy* solution to have to link against this "toolkit for manipulation of graphic images" just to create temporary files.  Consider this a -1 without the actual downvote.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: It's one of those ancient tools that no one has really needed for several decades.