# When writing to a newly created file, can I create the directory entry only after writing is completed?

Tags: linux, file, directory, filesystems

I'm writing a file that takes minutes to write.  External software monitors for this file to appear, but unfortunately doesn't monitor for inotify `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events, but rather checks periodically "the file is there" and then starts to process it, which will fail if the file is incomplete.  I cannot fix the external software.  A workaround I've been using so far is to write a temporary file and then rename it when it's finished, but this workaround complicates my workflow for reasons beyond the scope of this question¹.

Files are not directory entries.  Using hardlinks, there can be multiple pointers to the same file.  When I open a file for writing, both the inode and the directory entry are created immediately.  Can I prevent this?  Can I postpone the creation of the directory entry until the file is closed, rather than when the file is opened for writing?

Example Python-code, but the question is not specific to Python:

```py
fp = open(dest, 'w')  # currently both inode and directory entry are created here
fp.write(...)
fp.write(...)
fp.write(...)
fp.close()  # I would like to create the directory entry only here
```

Reading everything into memory and then writing it all in one go is not a good solution, because writing will still take time and the file might not fit into memory.

I found the related question *[Is it possible to create an unlinked file on a selected filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29002617/974555)*, but I would want to first create an anonymous/unnamed file, then naming it when I'm done writing (I agree with the answer there that creating an *inode* is unavoidable, but that's fine; I just want to postpone naming it).

Tagging this as [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), because I suspect the answer might be different between Linux and Windows and I only need a solution on Linux.

---

¹Many files are produced in parallel within dask graphs, and injecting a "move as soon as finished" task in our system would be complicated, so we're really renaming 50 files when 50 files have been written, which causes delays.

Comment: *but unfortunately doesn't monitor for inotify `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events*  Be glad it doesn't - that's **unreliable** because there's no actual indication that the file is complete.  Getting notified that file is closed is meaningless - you have no indication of **why** it was closed.

Comment: *Many files are produced in parallel within dask graphs, and injecting a "move as soon as finished" task in our system would be complicated, so we're really renaming 50 files when 50 files have been written, which causes delays.*  That's what you get for misusing a state-based data store such as a filesystem as an event-based messaging channel.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Right, perhaps ideally the code running inside dask should send a message "file successfully written".  The solution I'm exploring in my answer is not ideal.  I'm currently in the phase of exploring what's possible, then in a next step I can weigh the pros and cons of the different alternatives.  Even if what I ask for in this question is possible, I might not end up using it at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4174216/10678955